# NextJS persistent nested layout for tabs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to implement a persistent layout for a profile page. What I have currently is a persistent layout for the header and the rest of the content, which was no issue to implement. But with the profile view I am having some issues.

Layout components:

[image]

The difference is that I would like to load the orange content (persistent profile page elements) once, only the tabs (yellow) should be loaded dynamically.

In other words, header has to be always persistent, but the orange elements have to be persistent between profile pages (`/profile/index`, `/profile/content`, `/profile/about-me`, ...). Obviously there are other pages, besides `/profile/*`, which only consists of header and the rest of the page's contents.

Website structure:

- Homepage (/)
- Store page (/store)
- Login page (/login)
- Profile page (/profile/[ID], default subpage being index)
- - Index (/profile/[ID]/index)
- - Content (/profile/[ID]/content)
- - About me (/profile/[ID]/about-me)

I have tried doing this with wrapper layout, but the issue is that I have to obtain data for the profile page from else where. I also need this data to be sync and NOT loaded client-side.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have `Layout.tsx` as your main layout with your persistent header inside it.

Now you need to create a `ProfileLayout.tsx` component containing your persistent User profile info and persistent sidebar(for the matter any component you want to be persistent throughout the Profile pages) which will be wrapped by the `Layout` component like this:

```
//ProfileLayout.tsx

const ProfileLayout: FC = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
        .
        .
        // Persistent profile info
        .
        .
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default ProfileLayout
```

Now you just need to use this `ProfileLayout` as the layout of each of your Profile page like this:

```
// content.tsx
  
const Content = () => {
  return 'Content'
}

Content.Layout = ProfileLayout

export default Content
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some way in next.js where you can have shared layout across your app. I recommend following
[this article](https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/)

you can use **option 1** in the article for always rendering your header component

```
One way to add a persistent layout component to your site is to create a custom App component, and always render your site layout above the current page component in the component tree.
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I'm trying to implement this layout for the orange (profile page) components, not header. Header is already working fine with current layout setup.

Answer (score 0):

In nextjs you can create an `_app.tsx` file which is the parent page component for all pages.  Inside that you can apply logic on how to style components.

```
// /pages/_app.tsx

import router from 'next/router'

import Header from './header'
import Sidebar from './sidebar'

const UI = ({Component, pageProps}: AppProps) => {
  const router = useRouter()

  return <div id='ui'>
    // you can also apply logic here using router.pathname === '/path'
    // if you want to control which pages is showing header/sidebar
    <Header/>
    <div id='page'>
      <Sidebar/>
      <div id='content'>
        <Component {...pageProps}/> // nextjs pages
      </div>
    </div>
    <style jsx>{`
      #ui {
        position: relative;
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
      }

      #header {
        min-height: 20vh;
      }

      #page {
        flex: 1 1 auto; // so that page will fill the screen
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
      }

      #sidebar {
        min-width: 280px;
      }

      #content {
        flex: 1 1 auto; // so that content will fill the screen
      }
    `}</style>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: How would you go about server-side fetching of data that would be required in Sidebar component?

Comment: As it's not supported in nextjs I wouldn't, I also don't see many reasons for why it should be fetched serverside, I'd just fetch it client side using the sidebar component from my backend API or from nextjs API.

Comment: I see. Could you point me to any tutorials on how client side fetching is implemented from inside a react component or layout?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

fetch('https://example.com') // returns the data from that API

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction